# Django Rest api Update View form can't update single attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created an Employee CRUD in Django REST using generic views. when update view page is loaded  I couldn't find the current values in the fields. so I can't update a single value. when i update a single value it shows other fields must be required.

I need to update a single value. eg: Phonenumber
How can i do that?

```
class EmpUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmpModelSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3hI3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Slum.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFMjQ.png)

Comment: use PATCH for `partial_update` instead of PUT

Comment: Please, don't update images and links of images with code. Put it directly inside the question.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Use a `patch` method as it uses [partial_update](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L228)

```
class EmpUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmpModelSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Add your business logic if any
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note: Partial update just adds kwargs['partial'] = True and perform update operation.

DRF Source code:

```
    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```